# Simplify trigonometric formulae for re-spawning player on opposite edge of canvas

Tags: javascript, game-development, trigonometry

I'm making a js asteroid game that re-spawns the player on the opposite side of the screen when they fly off it completely. The spaceship/player is a triangle with points (30; 0), (-10; 10) (-10; -10) from its centre.

[image]

The code I produced only teleports the player onto the opposite edge when all these three points are gone from the screen (when spaceship cannot be seen).

[image: Demo:]

The complexity here comes from the fact that these three points are drawn on a canvas rotated with the spaceship, so then I need to find there x & y distance from the spaceship's center on the main-game canvas.

Here is the code I use for this, but I was wondering if anyone had an idea for a simpler approach?

```
var pointADistance = Math.cos(this.rotation) * 30;

var pointBDistance = Math.cos(Math.PI - this.rotation + 2.35619) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(10, 2) * 2);

var pointCDistance = Math.cos(Math.PI + this.rotation + 2.35619) * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(10, 2) * 2);
```

Comment: Why do you need to use trig for this?, you surely have all 3 points calculated somewhere to be able to draw the ship, so why not make sure all 3 points are within?.

Comment: The points are drawn on canvas rotated by the ships rotation angle, relative to the center of the spaceship. I need to use trig to basically plot these points on the x & y axis of the game-canvas which is horizontal/vertical.

Comment: Hi Coolpaper, you could test the rotation angle first, then you'd know which one of the 3 tests to do (also initialise and store your constant lengths for efficiency)- so your check would only involve 1 call to cos(). Alternatively you could consider just using a bounding rect- might look a bit clunky in practice though.

Comment: Thank you for the idea Gremto, checking the angle to determine which point would be closer to the wall make a lot of sense!

Comment: In old school games (the game you are recreating), the pixels would automatically "wrap around" the canvas. So a pixel that gets drawn at `605,0`, when the screen size is `600x400`, will automatically get drawn at `5,0`. I've been trying to achieve this effect on a html canvas, so far I only found the `pattern wrap` option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern  Another option could be to create a WebGL shader that does this.

Comment: And engines such as PIXI.js or even Three.js have the option to create meshes/shaders that automatically wrap the texture around.